# how to filter out certain numbers to add to a list according to a sequence?

Tags: python, list

Write a program that prints the following 45 pairs of numbers:

```
11
21
22
31
32
33
41
42
43
44
51
...

...
97
98
99
```

Note that the first numbers go from 1 to 9, and the second numbers start at 1 and go up to the value of the first number (9 times).

i have no idea where to even start with this. pretty sure I have to create a list and use a loop to add to it but idk how to filter those numbers out. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create two loops

1st from 1 to 9 and second from 1 to whatever first loop value is

take the values from two loops convert them to string add them so instead of arithmetic addition they get attached to each other as digits

convert them back to int and print

```
for i in range(1,10):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        myNum = int(str(i)+str(j))
        print(myNum)
```

```
11
21
22
31
32
33
41
42
43
44
51
52
53
54
55
61
62
63
64
65
66
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea here, if you use python 3.x

```
for i in range(1,10):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(f'{i}{j}', end=' ')
```

output:

1`1 21 22 31 32 33 41 42 43 44 51 52 53 54 55 61 62 63 64 65 66 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99`